# Conditions for intersection of two surjective functions in $\mathbb{R}^2$

Tags: real-analysis

Let $f:\mathbb R\to \mathbb R$ and $g:\mathbb R\to \mathbb R$ be surjective differentiable functions. Under what conditions do the two functions have at least one point of intersection?

I at first thought that the two functions must intersect if $f'(x)\neq g'(x)$, but this is not the case. A simple counterexample is  $f(x)=x^3$ and
$$g(x)=\begin{cases} 
      2x^3-1, x<0 \\
      \frac{x^3}{2}-1,x\geq0
   \end{cases}
$$
Is it possible to find specific conditions under which two functions meeting the given criteria will intersect?

Comment: Question is a bit too broad. Is there some specific application in mind? I could say they intersect if one is monotonically decreasing and the other is monotonically increasing. Of course this is sufficient but not necessary.  I hardly believe you can find necessary conditions.

Comment: @Mefitico There was no specific application; I was more curious if it were possible to find necessary conditions if they existed. If the question is too broad to allow for them to exist though then I will delete the question

Comment: I think there is no need to delete, but I asked for context mostly with the intent of saying "help me help you".

Comment: If there are numbers $a < b$ such that $f(a) - g(a)$ and $f(b) - g(b)$ have opposite signs, then they certainly intersect somewhere between $a$ and $b$. This would work for any continuous functions $f,g$.